# Shopware 6 Output logos in email with variable

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How can I output the sales channel logo by variable in Shopware 6?
We have several sales channels and I don't really want to create a separate email header for each channel.
I can't find anything in the documentation about this unfortunately.

Is that even possible?

Thanks for your info :-)

I have no idea how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible currently. The twig function `theme_config` which is used in the storefront template to retrieve the URL of the image isn't available within email templates. This is because mail templates aren't necessarily bound to sales channels. While they may be translated for languages used by specific sales channels, there's no direct link connecting mail templates to themes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)

Is there any other way to realize this?

Comment: The `salesChannel` variable should be available so you could have it in an if clause to use different images. `{% if salesChannel.name == "My Store" %}http://example.com/logo.png{% endif %}`

Comment: I have to ask something again :-)
Is there a variable with which I can see the ID of the sales channel?

Comment: `salesChannel.id` should work

Comment: Super. Thank you very much. Now it works. 

I still have one question :-)
Is there any way to automatically drag a channel's logo into a document without putting an image in the document? (Invoice etc.) without having to create a separate document for each channel?

Comment: Custom template is installed.

Does this need to be customized in the /includes/logo.html.twig file?